# Snowflake - A call of "CREATE NOTIFICATION INTEGRATION" producing a mystery error

Tags: azure, integration, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

This command:

```
create notification integration int_az_order_products_streaming
  enabled = true
  type = queue
  notification_provider = azure_storage_queue
  azure_storage_queue_primary_uri = 'https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.queue.core.windows.net/q-order-products'
  azure_tenant_id = '73XXXX-XXXXXX-2053d'
  ;
```

is getting this error:
`SQL compilation error: invalid value [QUEUE - AZURE_STORAGE_QUEUE] for parameter 'Integration Type'`

Anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

Is your Snowflake account hosted on AWS? This feature is currently limited to Snowflake accounts on the Microsoft Azure platform as noted in the documentation here.
https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/tables-external-azure.html

You can still connect to Azure and use Azure-based storage even on AWS Snowflake accounts.  The limitation is to the feature noted in the documentation for automatic refreshing.  Snowflake doesn't currently support auto-refresh cross-clouds at this time.

Even so, for automatic refreshing, you may be able to set this up with the tasks feature as a workaround:
https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/tasks.html

I am thinking a task could be setup to periodically refresh the external table. That would accomplish similar functionality.

Comment: I believe that the our Snowflake instance is hosted on AWS.  The instructions to set up the auto-load from Azure did seem fairly simple...now I know it is due to cloud proximity.  Is there a way to see what cloud your Snowflake instance is hosted on.

Comment: The easiest way I can think of is just to look at your Snowflake account's URL. The Azure accounts usually have "azure" right in the URL.  Here's some examples of the clouds and regions: https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/connecting.html#your-snowflake-account-name

Comment: This command also works (shows region and cloud):  select current_region();